# 2d tile map render rotation math?

Tags: mathematics, rendering, tilemap, tiles, raylib

I am working on a personal project and am trying to make a 2d tile map render that needs to handle rotation.

I am using raylib to handle the drawing stuff onto the screen and am using this function to draw a tile:

```
void DrawTexturePro(Texture2D texture, Rectangle sourceRec, Rectangle destRec, Vector2 origin, float rotation, Color tint);
```

How do I calculate the new coordinates of the tiles after the rotation and the individual rotation of each tile if I want to rotate the tile map?

I also need to figure how to do mouse click detection for tiles when they are rotated with their new coordinates and how to do ‘collision detection with cursor’ with rotated squares/tiles.

And due to the way the project is set up I cannot rotate the camera.

Extra info/diagram:

[image: Extra info]

Comment: When you say you have no means to rotate the camera, do you mean the entire rendering code from that point onwards is out of your control? Or do you have any way to alter the model-view-projection matrices for calculating the vertex positions?

Comment: No I need other items being rendered to not turn with the grid so I do not want to alter the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to transform the point by a rotation/transformation matrix.

Wikipedia has good information about using rotation matricies 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

θ is your angle
X,Y are your coordinates of your object (represented as a column vector/1D matrix)
X',Y' are your new, rotated coordinates

```
[X'] = [cosθ -sinθ][X]
[Y'] = [sinθ  cosθ][Y]
```

This is a small amount of matrix math equating to

```
X' = [cosθ * X] + [-sinθ * Y]
Y' = [sinθ * X] + [ cosθ * Y]
```

You can use transformation matrices for lots of operations such as translations, scaling, rotation, skewing, etc. They are widely used in 3D graphics

Answer (score -1):

get rotation flag from tile,parse it and swap coordinates from your vertexes

Here good engine and good example where you can find how to do it

https://github.com/oxygine/oxygine-framework/commit/3d02d81e0b3851bab705aaea72d5a0375c9ea432

Comment: Please elaborate as to why you suggest this is a solution to the problem,  and properly format your answer.

Comment: I add example about what i mean

Comment: Adding a link to an external site is not the way to go, as links die. This answer is not very useful in its current state.

Comment: How  links can die for official documentation ?

Comment: that library may not exist forever. It's also not specific to his problem

Comment: Its is not a library. It is an engine. Chance to disappear it equals of chance to disappear of boost,unity ,etc

Comment: This is just how the site's policy is. But, what if GitHub decides that all repos will cost money, and the engine decides to move to BitBucket?